# Python- peewee takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, peewee

I'm new at learn Python and in course python- connect to database sqlite in this code:

```
import os
import pewee

baza =  pewee.SqliteDatabase('test.db')

class BazaModel():
 database = baza

class Klasa(BazaModel):
 nazwa =  pewee.CharField(null=False)
 profil =  pewee.CharField(default='')

class Uczen(BazaModel):
 imie =  pewee.CharField(null=False)
 nazwisko =  pewee.CharField(null=False)
 klasa =  pewee.ForeignKeyField(Klasa, related_name='uczniowie')

baza.connect() 
baza.create_tables([Klasa, Uczen], True)
```

I have problem error :

> baza.create_tables([Klasa, Uczen], True) TypeError: create_tables()
>   takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Course is from 2016, so I think have a newer peewee version, but I don't know how fix it...

Comment: Just a side note, avoid using from pewee import *, it make unreadable code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3 arguments are your database, the list of tables, and the boolean : `some_obj.some_fun(obj1, obj2)` is translated by python as `some_fun(some_obj, obj1, obj2)`. This explains that it tells you you have 3 positional arguments, not 2.

You can see in [peewee doc](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Database.create_tables) that create_tables only takes one extra positional argument (two with the database). 
The third argument you're using is now a *keyword* argument (not a *positional* one), you have to specify what it is, i.e. you should write :

```
baza.create_tables([Klasa, Uczen], safe=True)
```

Comment: Thanks you so much!

Comment: please accept the answer (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it solved you problem